# Combining rn-fbsdk and react native linking objective-c code

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

After debugging, I found out why my app isn't receving the deep links.

It's because of the fb code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                            openURL:url
                                                  sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                         annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
              ];
// Add any custom logic here.
return handled;
}
```

How do you suppose to combine these for the rn-linking code, since this is also required:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

  NSString * scheme = (NSString*)url.scheme;
  NSString * fbScheme = @"fb123456789";

  if ([fbScheme isEqualToString:scheme]) {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance]
            application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
  } else {
    //Your other stuff here
  }
}
```

fixed it with this.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I combined linking, RN fbsdk, RN google signin

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                        openURL:url
                                              sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                     annotation:annotation
          ]
  || [RNGoogleSignin application:application
                         openURL:url
               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                      annotation:annotation
      ]
  || [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation
      ];

}
```